# Flask, Not Found The requested URL was not found on the server

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

i am following the https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-iii-web-forms
After i did the tutorial, and ran the flask program, it showed out the "Not Found The requested URL was not found on the server. " I have a github link to my directory below, please check it out. Thanks in advance.
I am using a windows 10 on python 3.8.9. I use VS code.

Github: https://github.com/HoHoHoCCH/flaskHelp

Here is my routes code if there is anything wrong there:

```
from flask import render_template
from app import app
from app.forms import LoginForm

app.route('/login/')
def login():
    form = LoginForm()
    return render_template('login.html', title='Sign In', form=form)
```

Answer (score 0):

can you tell what is in the address bar of your browser and how you are running the app. try removing the extra slash after login in you route.

Comment: ty, but what do you mean by "the address bar of your browser "? Sorry, but i am a bit confused. I am using cmd to run it using a virtual env

Comment: ty so much tho!

Comment: I was asking about the url when you visit the login page. like http://127.0.0.1:5000/login ,by the way you can mark this as correct answer if you want.

Comment: oh no worries i fixed it

Answer (score 0):

For `app.route('/login/')` you had and extra '/' after '/login'. Remove that and you will be good.

Comment: This repeats the previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67648253/2530121) to this question. Please check your answer has not already been given before posting. Thanks